# Javascript: Human verification, with custom questions

Tags: javascript, html, human-readable

I'm having trouble determining the correct term, for what I'm about to describe. I hope someone will know what I'm talking about and can give me the correct terminology.

I have a generic form that lets the user enter a name, number, and an e-mail. I would like to implement a form of "captcha-esq" verification. Server limitations prevent me from using something like Google's reCAPTCHA. I would like to implement something similar to what can be found on a wordpress site using **javascript**.

**The *user* would have to correctly answer 1 of 3 random challenge(questions) in order for the form to successfully submit and notify me.** If the response is incorrect, the form should not submit the data.
ie. Q: Do pigs fly?
 A: No
    Q:What's 2 + 2?
 A: 4
    Q: A PB & J sandwich, without the PB is what?
 A: J sandwich

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is a very broad question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JamesMonger op is looking for terms

Comment: You can't make a captcha purely client-side. The only thing that will stop is people, not bots.

Comment: Hi, you don't get to edit your question to remove all the text.  The correct thing to do is make sure your question is good enough before you ask it.

Comment: Again, do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct terminology for this would be "Bot prevention". Although "anti-spam" is also widely used.

Comment: The original question asked for the blanket term for this technology. Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks James; welcome to the internet. I'll remove the question to save your rep.